# Can a Scala trait copy its subclass?

Tags: scala, traits

I want to make a trait that can produce a copy of its subclass. The subclass is guaranteed to be a case class, so should have a `copy` method. What am I doing wrong here?

```
trait Copyable[C <: Copyable[C] with Product] {

  def specialCopy: C =
    this.asInstanceOf[C].copy() // doesn't compile

}
```

Comment: There is no `copy()` on `Product`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The subclass is guaranteed to be a case class

No, it isn't. `Product` can be implemented by non-case classes.

And even if it were, `copy` methods of different case classes are different methods with different signatures, there's no single `copy` method to call.

Though you can *mostly* implement `specialCopy` using reflection and `productIterator`. Approximately:

```
 def specialCopy = getClass.getConstructors()(0).newInstance(this.asInstanceOf[Product].productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[Object]].toSeq: _*)
```

This won't work for classes with more than one parameter list (including implicit parameters) or for inner classes.

Comment: +1 for `specialCopy` -- this does what I want. In fact I do have implicit parameters, but they are fixed (while the product fields can vary), so I can make this work.